# Query on users blocked

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help. I have to do a query and to see just the people where my id 1 is not present on the table users_blocked.

I tried like this:

```
SELECT 
U.first_name, U.sex, U.age, U.id, UB.request_user_id, UB.block_user_id
FROM users U, users_blocked UB
WHERE U.sex <> 'm'
AND NOT (UB.request_user_id = U.id AND UB.block_user_id = 1)
```

but it doesn't work

How can I see the just record 32 on the table users?

```
Table: users

id  | first_name  | sex | age
1   | Mark        | m   | 32
2   | Alice       | f   | 26
23  | Lory        | f   | 24
32  | Jenny       | f   | 25


Table: users_blocked

id | request_user_id | block_user_id
1  | 2               | 1
2  | 23              | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question right, you want to search all the records where block_user_id is not equal to 1 and records are present in both the tables. Mat be this below mentioned query will help you

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    U.first_name, U.sex, U.age, U.id, UB.request_user_id, UB.block_user_id
FROM users U
INNER JOIN users_blocked UB ON U.id = UB.block_user_id
WHERE U.sex <> 'm' AND UB.block_user_id != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from users u join users_blocked ub on u.id = ub.request_user_id where u.sex <> 'm' and ub.block_user_id != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably

```
SELECT u.id FROM users u 
INNER JOIN users_blocked ub ON u.id = ub.request_user_id
WHERE u.sex <> 'm' and ub.block_user_id <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to join `users` against `users_blocked` two times, because you want to join using two different columns (since you want users that have not records in users_blocked, in any of the these columns: `request_user_id` and `block_user_id`).

You should use a `LEFT JOIN` (if your first table in the `SELECT` is users), because first you need to have all of your users selected; if you used an INNER JOIN, any user that doesn't have a record in `users_blocked` wouldn't be selected.

Once you have that, you filter out all the records where both `block_user_id` and `request_user_id` are NULL. I suggest that you run the query without the `WHERE`  clause and with `SELECT *` to see more clearly how (and why) this works.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN users_blocked blocked ON blocked.block_user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN users_blocked requester ON requester.request_user_id = u.id
WHERE blocked.block_user_id IS NULL AND requester.request_user_id IS NULL
```